# How to host Web app on Azure's Windows Server 2012R2 VM (and resolve new site names)?

Tags: .net, azure, hosting, virtual-machine, web-hosting

Generally, having created Windows 2012R2 VM in Azure, the name of which is something.cloudapp.net, I have a default Web site hosted on IIS (it's in terns is reacheble from outside by something.cloudapp. net), but how to create another Web apps/ host them in IIS/selfhost (and absically, say self-host Nancy/Simple.web apps) on that VM? What whould be the domain name reacheble from outside? (how can I reach them from my PC browser), can I also set appache/nginx servers to the same VM and host webapps usig them and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You can setup as many web servers as you like. You could expose them externally using different ports or different domain names.

To do this using different domain names you would need to setup the CNAME records with your DNS provider to point to something.cloudapp.net and setup IIS to bind to only the correct domain name. (http://www.domainmonster.com/glossary/dns/cname/)

To do this using ports you would need to run your sites on different ports and allow incoming traffic on these ports. (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/28100eb3-6e9b-4012-a273-84062f4e293a/azure-firewall-how-to-allow-outbound-and-inbound-traffic-on-vm)

The best solution may be to run nginx/apache on port 80/443 and then use that as a reverse proxy to IIS.